# Unable to resolve published NPM module in project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, node-modules, npm-publish

I recently published a simple React module that I wrote in TypeScript. I tested my module by importing the local package into a project, and it worked flawlessly. However, now that I've published the module, whenever I try to import it into a project, I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/...
Module not found: Can't resolve '<module>' in '.../src/...'
```

Package is listed in both `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, and the module shows up in `node_modules`. Additionally, VS Code doesn't throw any fits, so I'm not quite sure what could be the issue.

Comment: I've seen something similar when I forgot to stop the dev server and restart it after installing a package.

Comment: @CharlieStanard I thought about that, but the package still wouldn't resolve after restarting the dev server. I even recloned my project and reinstalled the package and it wouldn't resolve.

Comment: is the package not built when published? is main field in pkgjson pointing to the right place? is it still linked from when you were doing development?

Comment: One thing that could go wrong is that the "main" field in package.json refers to a typescript file instead of the built javascript file that most interpreters could import.

Comment: @DaveAnkin It looks like my `"main"` field in `package.json` is indeed pointing at a TypeScript file. Let me change that and republish, I'll let you know how that works out.

Comment: @DaveAnkin It worked! Please submit that as an answer so I can accept it :D

Comment: @DaveAnkin If you don't submit an answer within the next day or so I'm just going to add my own and accept that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPM, being the "Node Package Manager" interprets packages as node modules. in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), it says it will try to load a folder by looking for a `package.json` file, and resolving the path in main relative to the folder it found.

So when publishing a package with a build step, always make sure to build it before its published (there is a `prepublish` hook for this, in the `scripts` object in `package.json`).

The other thing is to make sure that the package being published refers to the correct `main`, `bin` (if applicable), and `module` (if applicable) paths in the `package.json` file. if the source file is `src/mylib.coffee` and the built file is `dist/mylib.js`, the package.json must contain `{ "main": "dist/mylib.js" }` in order that someone installing this module as a dependency into their `node_modules` folder would require the correct file.

in short make sure "main" in package.json points to the right file!